# Send mail via amazon ses with Laravel 5.5 for user verifacation

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I create a web application with laravel. All thing is ok in xampp server but user verification is not working when i launch it in aws ec2. I use gmail for sending email to users.

This error is shown:
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 64-v6sm12086194pfa.120 - gsmtp "

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try disabling then re-enabling the access for less secure apps : 
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Here is a thread that could help you, they talk about the Google Authenticator Verification also which might be causing you issues if you've enabled it : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-send-mail-through-smtp-gmail-com

Comment: all things is ok in localhost but not working in ec2